# IBM Document translator using WP_Http_Curl I'm Getting the Error Message like Error:415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: wordpress, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, content-type

```
$filename = ABSPATH.'wp-content/uploads/sample.txt';
        $filetype = wp_check_filetype('sample.txt');
        $file = @fopen( $filename, 'r' );   
        $file_size = filesize( $filename ); 
        $file_data = fread( $file, $file_size );

            $postBody = array(
                'file' => $file_data,
                'file_content_type'=>'text/plain',
                'filename'=>'sample.txt',
                'model_id'=>'en-fr'
            );
            $response=wp_remote_request(
                'https://api.jp-tok.language-translator.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/9ccfc671-1c75-40b6-ad45-b46ae4b53979/v3/documents?version=2018-05-01',
                array(
                    'method' => 'POST',
                    "body"     => $postBody,
                    "headers"  => array(
                    'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . $auth,
                    'Content-Type'=>'text/plain',
                    'Accept'=>'text/plain',
                     )
                )
            );
            print_r($response);
```

---

its gives 415 Unsupported Media Type,
I'm Giving the correct Content-Type for the file.
myfile name is sample.txt so that i add a **Content-Type** as **text/plain**
how to solve this issue.

---

Answer (score 0):

As you are invoking the service through a word-press plugin, I think you are restricted to usage as defined by the API documentation for cURL - https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/language-translator#translatedocument

The API documentation suggests that in your case the request body only needs the file body and translation information.

```
            $postBody = array(
                'file' => $file_data,
                'model_id'=>'en-fr'
            );
```

and you don't need to specify the `Content-Type` or `Accept`